# What do original, current, and new value mean in the context of pricing storage updates?

Tags: storage, gas-price

I've heard these terms thrown around in discussions surrounding storage pricing in the EVM. But what do they mean, more precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These terms were first defined in [EIP-1283](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1283), and they refer to the different states that a storage value can have during the execution of a transaction.

Here's a table that explains the three terms:

| Term | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Original value | The value that was in storage at the beginning of the transaction or function call. |
| Current value | The value in storage at the time you are executing the `SSTORE` operation. |
| New value | The value you are trying to store. |

It is worth noting that in most cases, the original value will **coincide** with the current value.

Here's an example contract to hammer the concept home:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.21;

// All storage slots are assumed to be cold, so an extra 2100 gas is needed for each operation
// See EIP-2929
contract StorageWriteExamples {
    uint256 public value;

    // original value = 0
    // current value  = 0
    // new value      = 1
    // sstore cost    = 22100 (20000+2100)
    function call_me_first() public {
        value = 1;
    }

    // original value = 1
    // current value  = 1
    // new value      = 42
    // sstore cost    = 5000 (2900+2100)
    function call_me_second() public {
        value = 42;
    }

    // original value = 42
    // current value  = 1
    // new value      = 1337
    // sstore cost    = 100
    function call_me_third() external returns (uint256) {
        call_me_first();
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();
        value = 1337;
        return startGas - gasleft();
    }
}
```

Notes:

- In most cases, the original value will **coincide** with the current value.
- You might want to take a look at the `SSTORE` reference on [evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/#55?fork=shanghai) (they even have a calculator for estimating the gas cost and refund!)
- While it is EIP-1283 which defined these terms, the most up-to-date logic can be found in [EIP-2200](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2200) and [EIP-2929](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2929)