# Why don't ETH transfers cost more when the recipient's balance is zero?

Tags: gas, gas-price, transfer

The `SSTORE` opcode has differential pricing depending on what the [original, current, and new](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/154979/what-do-original-current-and-new-value-mean-in-the-context-of-pricing-storage) storage values are (see [EIP-2200](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2200) for the full details). In short, the idea is that setting a zero value to a non-zero value (e.g. 0 to 42) costs significantly more than setting a non-zero value to another non-zero value (e.g. 42 to 1337).

However, all standard ETH transfers cost the same, namely, 21,000 gas. Why?

Why don't ETH transfers cost more when the recipient's balance is zero (compared to when it is not zero)?

For example, why not something like ~5k extra?

| Sender | Recipient | Recipient's Balance | Gas Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Bob | 4.2 ETH | 21,000 |
| Alice | Charlie | 0 ETH | 26,000 |

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has to do with how accounts are stored on disk, basically once an account is created the entire tuple (nonce, balance, code, storageRoot) always exists, even when balance = 0. note that storageRoot is just the hash of that account's storage trie.

on the other hand, the storage trie is sparse on disk. all values are 0 by default, so by setting a storage slot to 0 you can also remove it from disk.

Comment: "basically once an account is created the entire tuple ... always exists" - ok so what if the recipient account does NOT exist at all? No nonce, no code, no anything. Just sending ETH to an empty EOA.

Comment: Isn't the exact amount arbitrary, would guess it makes more sense to have a consistent value for a native transfer, than one that is "5000" more or less in some situations.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Tranferring ethers to an inexistent account will charge an extra 25000, see EIP-161 for the extra details https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-161.

Comment: @Ismael that's for `CALL` and `SELF-DESTRUCT`.  How about non-contract transfers of ETH between EOAs?

Comment: if you send to a non-existent account, it will create the account. so the tuple will exist at that point.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Increasing the cost for that case could break a lots of scripts that depends on 21k gas. In particular exchanges use EOA instead of contracts to move ether around.

Comment: gotcha, so the answer to my OP question is basically "path dependence". It *should* have cost more to transfer ETH to empty accounts, but because Ethereum wasn't designed like that in the early days, we're stuck with the current design to ensure backward compatibility.